# two methods for after_add callback on mongoid relations

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3

How can we have two methods for after_add callback on mongoid relations. Both the methods need to do different things?

has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, after_add: method1, after_add: method2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, after_add: [:method1, :method2]
```